# Error en la gestión de etiquetas activas

Tags: bug, estado-completado, etiquetas, búsqueda, preguntas-activas

No sé si le pasará a alguno más... entiendo que sí.

Yo tengo preparado un acceso directo a Stack Overflow para que directamente me filtre las etiquetas que normalmente suelo responder:

```
[c++] or [c] or [qt] or [c++11] or [c++14] or [c++17]
```

Ahora bien, hoy he notado que si cambio de pestaña, por ejemplo de "activas" a "votos", la búsqueda se desconfigura, quedando así:

```
[c] or [c] or [qt] or [c] [11] or [c] [14] or [c] [17]
```

Con lo que un montón de preguntas quedan ocultas sin yo darme cuenta.

No sé si es algún problema de Stack Overflow o si puede estar relacionado con alguna actualización puñetera del navegador... y la única forma de averiguarlo que se me ha ocurrido es preguntando por aquí :)

¿A vosotros también os pasa?

Comment: Sí, y creo haber leído un reporte de esto en MSE... ¡Eso pasa por programar en un lenguaje de una sola letra! :-P

Comment: Yo no aprecio ese comportamiento. En mi caso tengo `[c#] or [vb.net] or [.net] or [asp] or [asp.net] or [visualstudio]` por ejemplo y no me pasa, por lo que parece que el problema es al gestionar `++`

Comment: Parecería como si lo tratara como un valor _urlencodeado_ donde `+` es un espacio, y entonces lo pone como un separador o algo.

Comment: Por cierto, una forma de alternativa es seleccionando todas esas etiquetas como favoritas y buscando `intags:mine`

Comment: Sí, claro, es el `+`... Hay varios reportes de bugs, pero no encontré ninguno con suficientes votos o una respuesta oficial... Con lo de 1 letra me refería a que sino, podría buscar algo como `[python*]` para todas sus versiones

Comment: @Mariano Aquí hay un reporte que tiene la etiqueta "status-by-design": [Bug with tags with plus in name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77757/289691)

Comment: @Rubén Lo leí. No obstante, habla de otro caso en particular (siendo [tag:c++] la excepción), no de por qué https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B+or+c+or+c%23?sort=votes elimina el `%2B` de la búsqueda, que aparentemente se debe a una doble decodificación. Están relacionados, pero no creo que aplique el estado por diseño acá

Comment: @Mariano me retracto, pongamos en cuestión el estado-por-diseño para este caso, y de acuerdo a [What symbols/characters are not allowed in tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298981/348460) dice que solamente las etiquedas que empiecen con [tag:c++], [tag:visual-c++-2010] y [tag:g++4.8] serán permitidas. Por lo tanto, me parece que sí se trata de una falla de la matrix. Nota que solamente pasa cuando haces la combinación de etiquetas separándolas por el `or`, si buscas de forma independiente no se presenta la falla.

Comment: Reportado también en SOen un poco antes: [Bug when combining boolean search operators with tags containing plus signs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362508/1983854)

Comment: Bueno, viendo todo el jaleo que hay montado ya me quedo un poco más tranquilo... no es cosa mía jejejeje

Comment: Hoy por fin ya está resuelto el problema. Las etiquetas con `++` ya vuelven a funcionar correctamente

Comment: @fedorqui el asunto lleva solucionado 4 días... pero ese enlace no parece tener nada que ver :S

Comment: Jua, me hice la picha un lío :D Efectivamente, fue el 1 de febrero y Marc Gravell lo reportó en [Bug when combining boolean search operators with tags containing plus signs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362816/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui ese enlace sí es el bueno :)